# static size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t max) -- why a static return value?

Tags: c, syntax, strlen

I might be going insane, but I don't think I've ever seen this in c++ (though my reference code is in C).  Why is there a static on the return value of the code here and what impact does it have?  I don't think I've ever seen a static function outside class scope (but obviously C doesn't have classes and this probably has a different syntactical meaning).

```
/* just like strlen(3), but cap the number of bytes we count */
static size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t max) {
    register const char *p;
    for(p = s; *p && max--; ++p);
    return(p - s);
}
```

From http://www.zeuscat.com/andrew/software/c/strnlen.c.

Comment: It should be noted that the names like `strnlen` for your own functions are a very bad idea. `str*` is reserved by ISO C and POSIX if `string.h` is included, and in fact POSIX defines its own non-`static` `strnlen` which will conflict with this `static` one.

Comment: I'm not writing my own really, I just like to review things like this occasionally since interviewers frequently use this kind of question :) but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx) is not on the **return type but on the function definition**.

static functions don't have external linkage basically they are only visible to other functions in the same file.

Comment: Does this work in C++ too for namespace-scope functions (non class)?